# Phonegap JavaScript php include

Tags: php

Is it possible load a page with php inc with phone gap using JavaScript to load it. This would make html in phone gap really easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only can use php with phonegap with web services and AJAX. A mobile can't interpret php by default.